# rails 3.1, weird find_template NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to upgrade a fairly complicated app from rails 3.0 to rails 3.1, suddently requesting any action at all in the app results in a fatal error:

```
NameError (undefined method `find_template' for class `#<Class:0x2baa87725d50>')
```

No stack trace.  No additional information. Grep'ing for "find_template", it does not seem to be ANYWHERE in my source. Although I've got a bunch of gem dependencies, I guess it could be in one of them.

But I'm thinking this is a weird error message which means something OTHER than I actually have code calling #find_template. Something weird.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: As often, right after I post it, I figure it out. 

It was the render_inheritable gem.  Very similar functionality is built into Rails 3.1, and the previous render_inheritable gem is incompatible with Rails 3.1. 

Hopefully this will be an aid to googlers, I didn't find much myself.

Comment: Please put it in an answer then. Someone coming on this page will see it faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As often, right after I post it, I figure it out. It was the render_inheritable gem. Very similar functionality is built into Rails 3.1, and the previous render_inheritable gem is incompatible with Rails 3.1. Hopefully this will be an aid to googlers, I didn't find much myself.